# twitter bootstrap, html controls and asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am working on a website developed using the twitter bootstrap and asp.net.

I would like to know how to access a html control from the code behind page.
For example,

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="name">
Your Name</label>
<div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="ApplicantName" id="AppName" placeholder="First Name and Last Name" >
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I get or set the value of the ApplicantName textbox?

Comment: surely this is such basic stuff, a first tutorial would cover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `runat` attribute to the control and set the value as `server` and it will be accessible in codebehind.

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" runat="server" />
```

Now in codebehind, you can access it.

```
txtName.Value="this is set from codebehind";
```